# How to deal with general errors in Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to set up rails API, getting this error, both through console and in actual API requests:

```
Rack app error handling request { POST /login } #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController
```

This is my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    before_action :authorized

    def encode_token(payload)
        JWT.encode(payload, 's3cr3t')
    end

    def auth_header
        #requesting the header type of authorization (with token) that we will declare through our api requests
        # { Authorization: 'Bearer <token>' }
        request.headers['Authorization']
    end

    def decoded_token
        if auth_header
            #going to take the token and decode it
            # we're only concerned about the first index which will be a token with key of *user_id*
            token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
            # header: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>' }
            begin
                JWT.decode('s3cr3t', true, algorithm: 'HS256')
            rescue JWT::DecodeError
                nil
            end
        end
    end

    def logged_in_user
        #consults decode_token to check the header for valid information
        if decoded_token
            user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id']
            @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        end
    end

    def logged_in?
        #returns true or false
        !!logged_in_user
    end

    def authorized
        #consults logged_in? see see if user is authorized
        render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
    end
end
```

Of course I would like to sort this error specifically (syntax error?) but not sure how to tackle general errors (beyond status codes) in Rails API. Is there a good practice I should be following?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create this project fresh with the ``--api`` option or is this a 'standard' rails app that you are adding APIs to? Also, what version of Rails?

Comment: Created fresh with the ```--api``` option. It is Rails 6.0.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NameError: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController`, where is your `ApplicationController` defined? It seems like `ActionText` requires it to be in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and possibly inherited from `ActionController::Base`.

As you develop an API I don't expect you need ActionText though and just accidentally load it. You should have a look in your `config/application.rb` file and look what gets loaded. If there is `require 'rails/all'` you should only load what you really need, e.g.

```rb
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
```

> but not sure how to tackle general errors (beyond status codes) in Rails API

In terms of general errors, you can e.g. use a `rescue_from` like this

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access # self defined exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :show_errors

  rescue_from 'MyAppError::Base' do |exception|
    render xml: exception, status: 500
  end

  private
    def deny_access
      ...
    end

    def show_errors(exception)
      exception.record.new_record? ? ...
    end
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from

For general errors it's not really needed to have a `rescue_from StandardError` as this is the default behaviour of Rails. Rails has a middleware called `PublicExceptions` which does (mostly) what you want so you can just let the StandardError propagate.

Instead of `{ error: "Internal Server Error" }` it will render this

```rb
{ 
  status: status, 
  error: Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES.fetch(status, Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[500]) 
}
```

which in case of an exception will render `{ status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error" }`. This should be a reasonable compromise.

For development you could think about adapting this middleware. You can set it with `config.exceptions_app`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/PublicExceptions.html

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb#L14

Comment: Great answer - it cleared a lot up for me. In terms of where ```application_controller``` is located, it is in the standard place ```app/controllers/application_controller.rb``` but rather inherits from ```ActionController::API```. Will implement for errors with what you have said :)